# Win32API: how to create a shortcut (.lnk file)

Tags: winapi, shortcut, jna

I'm a Java developer, so please excuse my ignorance.

I want to create a shortcut to an executable, e.g., in the user's autostart or send-to folder (I don't want an installer to do that, because the installer usually is run by an administrator). What API (C preferred) I could use for that task (maybe using JNA)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not let the installer do it for you?

Comment: You could do it using [JScript or VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fywyxt64%28VS.85%29.aspx) using the Windows Scripting Host.  Though I don't know how you'd do it using or integrating JNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hans indicated, it requires COM (via ShellLinkObject or [WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys%28VS.85%29.aspx)). In Java you can call COM objects using a Java to COM bridge. There are a few available, ranging from free to commercial. A couple that I know of are:

- [Java2COM](http://www.nevaobject.com/_docs/_java2com/java2com2.htm)
- [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/)
- [JCOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/)

Answer (score 1):

It requires using COM, ShellLinkObject from shell32.dll.  No idea what that takes in Java, but you'll find C# code in my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9e23a82c-8bed-4b96-8b9a-4c2b6136a622/).