# Java finding file type

Tags: java, file, types, shortcut

im writing a little project, that open files or shortcuts. In process I found problem.

Question is simple.
How can I get difference btw file or shortcut? What java commands should I use and search for?

Example

```
if (fileIsShortcut) {
    return variable1;
} else {
    return variable2;
}
```

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "shortcut" - are we talking about Windows shortcuts (which are just plain `.lnk` files), Mac Finder aliases or POSIX-style symbolic links?

Comment: To Java a Windows shortcut is just a plain file whose name happens to end in `.lnk`, so if all you care about is whether or not a particular file is a shortcut then just check the name.  If you need to work out what the shortcut points _to_, then I'm not aware of any pure Java way to do that.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3995097/592139) discusses some native bridge libraries that might help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
public static boolean isSymlink(File file) throws IOException {
  if (file == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("File must not be null");
  File canon;
  if (file.getParent() == null) {
    canon = file;
  } else {
    File canonDir = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
    canon = new File(canonDir, file.getName());
  }
  return !canon.getCanonicalFile().equals(canon.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

Comment: Somehow it cant find .lnk at end. That boolean return false.

Comment: this.test = new File("testSh.exe - Shortcut");



isSh = isSymlink(this.test);

and still return false;

Comment: because "testSh.exe - Shortcut" is relative to the program running path, provide the full path like "c:\\my\\dir\\testSh.exe - Shortcut.lnk"

what you provided is not a file.

Comment: i gave 
this.test = new File("C:\\Users\\Macas\\workspace\\Shortcut_Manager_1dalis_openFile\\src\\testSh.exe - Shortcut.lnk");

still return false, maybe I made mistake somewhere :s

Comment: check if the file exists  System.out.println(myFile.exists());

Comment: try to print   System.out.println(myFile.getCanonicalPath());
  System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath());  and tell me if its the same

Comment: that means its not a link. thats some strange file :\  because canomialpath resolves links

Comment: I have tried to create new shortcut and test it, but it works same. Thanks for your time and help, maybe I will google something now, not gonna take your precious time anymore. Have a good day :) Need to take a break.